# Incorrect credential on sending email with Flutter

Tags: flutter

I try to use Flutter mailer 3.0.2 's sample code from: https://pub.dev/packages/mailer#-readme-tab-
but when I try to run the code it throws an exception saying: 
I/flutter (25924): Incorrect username / password / credentials

The username and password are correct, I tried two gmail accounts.
What can be wrong?

Comment: You can get more help when you post some code and show what you have done.

Comment: `final smtpServer = gmail(username, password);
final message = Message()
    ..from = Address(username, 'Your name')
    ..recipients.add('destination@example.com')
    ..subject = 'Subject'
    ..html = "<h1>Test</h1>";`

Comment: `try {
    final sendReport = await send(message, smtpServer);

    print('Message sent: ' + sendReport.toString());
  } on MailerException catch (e) {
    print('Message not sent.');
    for (var p in e.problems) {
      print('Problem: ${p.code}: ${p.msg}');
    }
  }`

Answer (score 0):

Go and turn off your security of gmail:
https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps

Comment: I was getting same although using correct username and password with less secure app access but using one setting everything working fine now..  Go to Settings>Forwarding and POP/IMAP > Enable IMAP access , it will not show any error now